# How to Nicely (Ideally Uniformly) Approximate Inhomogeneous System of Two ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, asymptotics, systems-of-equations, perturbation-theory

I have a nonlinear system of ODEs of the form:
$$
\dot{k} = k(t)^α-gk(t)-c(t)\\
\dot{c} = \frac{\alpha k(t)^{\alpha-1}-g-\rho + (1-\gamma)\frac{g}{A_0+gt}}{\gamma}c(t)
$$
with associated initial condition $k(0)=k_0$ and terminal condition given by the transversality condition: $\lim_{t\to\infty}  e^{-\rho t+(1-\gamma)\log(A(0)+gt)-\log(1-\gamma) }c(t)^{-\gamma}k(t)=0.$ In practice, I take the transversality condition to mean $\lim_{t\to\infty} k(t)=K$, where $K$ is found to be: $$K=(\frac{g+\rho}{\alpha})^{\frac{1}{\alpha-1}}$$
and $\lim_{t\to\infty} c(t) = C$, where $C$ is found to be:
$$
C= K^α - gK. 
$$

I would like to check that the numerical solution I get from a boundary method `bvp5c` in Matlab is reasonable.

I had planned to use the method of matched asymptotics, expanding around $t=0$ and $t=\infty$, which would replace $\frac{g}{A_0+gt}$ with $\frac{g}{A_0}$ and $0$, but unfortunately have been unsuccessful so far in an analytical solution near these points. It is not obvious to me what a good 'semi-analytical' solution should be.
Any suggestions on how I might get a good approximation to the solution would be greatly appreciated.

I should add there is a non-negativity constraint on k,c such that $k(t)\geq0, c(t)\geq0$ with $g,\rho,\gamma,\alpha>0$.